# UV Packing Roadblock

Tags: 3dsmax, uv-mapping, 3d-modeling

I noticed that when I was unwrapping and packing UV's in 3DS Max, that about 75% of the map was taken up by a bunch of repetitive small parts, because of their unique shape and inability to fit somewhere else. It's because of this that they turned out the way they did:

[image]

This is a problem for me because now I don't have much texture space for the important UV islands such as the sides of the gun handle. The circled part in viewport mode is the section that matches with parts like the one circled in UV editing, and there are a lot of them. I need them to be scaled proportionately because they are already small enough that they'll barely have any pixels on them anyways. Perhaps ovelrap them and use the same part of the texture for every other, or every third ridge? At this point I'm not sure. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused what I'm looking at here; is that model a handle for a gun? If so, it *seems* that you're modelling are far too high a fidelity for games; those ridges you're baking in to the model may not need to be actual geometry.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but aside from the point :P

Comment: I figured since its a small gun, a little extra detail wouldnt hurt :)

Comment: On the contrary, a little extra detail can hurt significantly in many cases; you pay for the geometry and the texture complexity (and in this case the UV unwrapping issues) regardless. I have had scenarios where artists put "a little extra detail" into the trigger of a gun that, when removed, doubled our framerate. So it's important to consider the context of the model and where you can or can't sacrifice detail. I don't actually have a great answer for you, I just wanted you confirm what the model was in case others need to know.